# JQuery Slider not working with MVC4

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have tried to create a slider with a minimum value of 1 and a max value of 10.

Once the value of the slider is set, I want to send this value to the database via a @Html.HiddenFor tag.

When I try and run this code, my database value afterwards is always 0.

I don't think I have linked the Jquery, the slider & the MVC call up correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

`<input type="range" name="property" id="slider-range-min" onclick ="HandleSlider()" value="5" min="1" max="10"  />`

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuestionOne, new { @id = "qualslid" })

   $(function HandleSlider() {

    $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 5,
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#qualslid").val(ui.value);
             alert($("#qualslid").val());   
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Please check spell `"qualslid"` and `$("#qualsid")`

Comment: Thanks, hadn't noticed that, its still not working however

Comment: Your `alert()` would fail because you forgot the parenthesis on the `val()` method. I would recommend checking the console in your browser for further errors.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed the val() now but its still not working. I'm only using the alert as a way to test that the slider is selecting a value

Comment: Yes but alert  should be after `$("#qualslid").val(ui.value);`

Comment: Ive added the alert underneath the value, its still not working. I need to check if the slider is actually picking up values to transfer at all

Comment: check console for errors